# Visual Studio creating duplicate cshtml files

Tags: c#, razor, visual-studio-2015

Has anyone else had this problem? VS2015 Community keeps creating duplicates of my views. There is one other developer working on these, with github for version control. It only appears to be a problem on one branch.

[image: visual studio]

They're not true duplicates in the sense that if you delete one, the other is empty and the project fails to compile. Anyone else had this?

Comment: Both the files have the same content? Did you look in the csproj file to see if there are two Include of same file? If so, you can try modifying the csproj file manually to remove one Include and reloading the project in visual studio.

Comment: Thanks Chetan. Good suggestion, I was able to manually remove the duplicate includes from the csproj file and that has solved it. Any idea how this occurs in the first place.

Comment: Most probable cause of this could be inproper merge of project file. Sometime when we rely on automatic merge done by merge tool. That can cause the issue merge tool don't have intelligence to verify duplicate entries in csproj file.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds about right. We've had a hectic period with a lot of merges going on. If you'd like to answer the question I'd be happy to mark it answered so you get the credit!

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @Chetan Ranpariya above this is the result of heavy merging by multiple developers using the Visual Studio merge tools, which failed to resolve. Problem solved by unloading the project startup file in VS, copying to Excel, removing duplicate  statements and pushing back into VS and reloading the project.